# How to get correct content size of a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here are 2 blocks and first of them has click handler which assigns `scrollWidth` of the block to it's `width` property. There no padding or borders, but when the property is assigned, one word is wrapped to the next line.

As I understand it happens because `scrollWidth` returns `270`, when the value visible in web inspector is `270.08`. If I set `width` value to `270.08` the word won't be wrapped to the next line.

**How can I get real width of content including fractional part?**

By the way, `getComputedStyle(...).width` returns `"270.078px"`, but this method is not suitable in case if block has overflow. I need size of the contents.

The second click on div will set `width` to it's compuded value.

https://jsfiddle.net/0dqzvw4r/

```js
document.querySelector('p').addEventListener('click', function first(event) {
  var width = this.scrollWidth;
  var real = getComputedStyle(this).width;
  
  console.log(width);
  console.log(real);
  
  this.style.width = width + 'px';
  
  this.removeEventListener('click', first);
  this.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    this.style.width = real;
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Shrikhand', cursive;
}

p {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shrikhand" rel="stylesheet">
<p>How to get correct content size?</p>
<p>How to get correct content size?</p>
```

More complex example:

Same thing with horizontal scroll. After assigning `width` property `white-spase` is set to normal. The first block gets exactly `scrollWidth` and the second one gets 1 pixel more.

```js
document.querySelector('p').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  var width = this.scrollWidth;
  console.log(width);
  this.style.width = width + 'px';
  this.nextElementSibling.style.width = width + 1 + 'px';
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Shrikhand', cursive;
}

p {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 10em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}

p[style] {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shrikhand" rel="stylesheet">
<p>How to get correct content size?</p>
<p>How to get correct content size?</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) seems to work for you:

```js
document.querySelector('p').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  var width = this.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  console.log(width);
  this.style.width = width + 'px';
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Shrikhand', cursive;
}

p {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shrikhand" rel="stylesheet">
<p>How to get correct content size?</p>
<p>How to get correct content size?</p>
```

Comment: Nice. Also have a nice compatibility http://caniuse.com/#feat=getboundingclientrect.

Comment: @Qwertiy: isn't it an option to substract border widths and paddings from that?

Comment: @DanOvidiuBoncut, in case if I have `overflow: auto` and `offsetWidth` is smaller than `scrollWidth` no.

Comment: @Qwertiy - I understand that it may have an overflow but would it be ok to contain that text into another element? Just an ideea.

Comment: @DanOvidiuBoncut, you mean add additional element and get its computed size? That's possible, of course, but it would be much better witout it :)

Answer (score 2):

This returns 270.078px. I think this will work for you.

```js
document.querySelector('p').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  var width = window.getComputedStyle(this).width;
  console.log(width);
  this.style.width = width + 'px';
  
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Shrikhand', cursive;
}

p {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shrikhand" rel="stylesheet">
<p>How to get correct content size?</p>
<p>How to get correct content size?</p>
```

Comment: Updated the question.